# Endpoint in Azure Machine Learning not consumable

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a pipeline in Azure Machine Learning Designer. Below is the training pipeline. As you can see I have created a custom python model as I have a requirement to use an external package known as K-Modes (`pip install modes`). I have created a real-time inference pipeline off the back of the training pipeline and it ran successfully. When I deploy the inference pipeline, it is in a healthy state however I can not consume or test it.

In python, I get this error when trying to consume it.

```
{'error': {'code': 500, 'message': 'Internal Server Error. Run: Server internal error is from Module Score Model', 'details': ''}}
```

The `Module Score Model` has completed successfully and is green in the inference pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Hi Bryce, after looking at your issue, it seems we need more logs/info to debug. Could you please send us your workspace and subscription info? You can do this by submitting a feedback on the top right corner of the studio portal (the smiley face). You can also contact me via luzhan@microsoft.com if you want.